# Byte array and hex addresses

Tags: java

I have the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] exeBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(EXE_PATH).toPath());
    int decAddr = Integer.parseInt("4b613f8", 16);
    String hexByte = Integer.toHexString(exeBytes[decAddr]);
    System.out.println(hexByte);
}
```

and it prints `2e`, but when in the hex editor I can definitely see `55`.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong with the conversion or `Files.readAllBytes` reads the file in a different way I see it in the hex editor?

Hex editor view - [image]

140000000 is the first byte address

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` instead of just using `0x4b613f8` ?

Comment: @Michael that was the easiest way I could think of, but that doesn't matter

Comment: Can you actually show the offset on a hexadecimal editor?

Comment: Seems really strange. P.S. Try use literal 0x4b613f8  as Michael suggests just to debug-check.

Comment: what about other addresses? like 0x00  0x100 ets? does they works correctly?

Comment: @Bogdan address 0 works correctly, conversion to0x4b613f8 does nothing, just tried it. I'll post a hex editor screen in a minute

Comment: @m0skit0 just updated the post, check out the hex editor view

Comment: Add the image to your question, not as a link to an external site. Also, does `exeBytes.length` match the size of the file?

Comment: @Michael yes, it matches exactly, also updated image

Comment: What do you mean 140000000 is the first byte address?

Comment: @Wiktor You are trying to read the byte at `0x4b613f8`, but the screenshot shows the content (somehow) at address `0x144b613f8`. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @m0skit0 edited my post, check it out

Comment: @Progman updated

Comment: @Wiktor Posting a second screenshot does not explain what this offset means. When you open your file in a normal/different hexeditor, at which address it the value you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The program shown in question seems to be some disassembler/decompiler and not just an hex-editor (Ghidra?).

The loaded file is apparently a [Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) file or a DOS executable (starts with `MZ`). It consists of different sections and a [Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Layout) that is not loaded linearly to memory, that is, the file location is not the same as memory location (not even relative to start of file/memory storage).

To get the correct file index, probably the index in the corresponding section must be converted using the sections headers... but I'm just a Java developer.

Comment: Indeed it's correct. OP is trying to use the wrong addresses.